# invoking constructors of struct in functions, C++

Tags: c++, function, reference, constructor, struct

Here is the approximate code of my question. First, we have a struct with a constructor:

```
struct Pair{
Pair(int a, int b): (first (a) , second (b) ) {}
int first;
int second;
};
```

which is used in a map

```
map<string, Pair> mymap;
```

I would like to initialize this map in a function

```
void f(map<string, Pair>* mymap, string c,int x, int y )
{
(*mymap)[c]=Pair(x,y);
}
```

But the compiler says first that it could not find an appropriate constructor and then the next lines are that not enough arguments are provided for the constructor.

A friend of mine told me that I should write the function like this:

```
void f(map<string, Pair>& mymap, const string& c,int x, int y )
{
  if (mymap.find(c) != mymap.end()) {
    mymap[c] = Pair(x,y);
   }
}
```

**But he could not explain why *Type&* should be used here instead of *Type* *, and I would like to clarify this point.** Can anybody explain?

Comment: @philippe I don't see how that helps.

Comment: 1. your friend duplicated some code that is already assumed to be there. Map needs to find the key in order to make the insertion anyway.
2. Reference or pointer doesn't really matter in this case.
3. You need a default ctor for operator[] to work
4. I'm too scared to post this as an answer. SO might eat me alive.

Comment: @pwned: You should not fear SO... I would have upvoted that answer --I have basically answered the same. Sorry if you had a bad experience in the past, and hope to get some answers from you some time soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `operator[]` in a map requires that the value type is default constructible. If you don't want your `Pair` to be default constructible, you will have to avoid using `operator[]`:

```
void f(map<string, Pair>& mymap, string c,int x, int y )
{
   mymap.insert( std::make_pair(c,Pair(x,y)) );
}
```

You may have misunderstood what your friend suggested. The problem with `operator[]` is not that it requires the default constructor *if* it needs to create a new element, but that it requires it *in case it might need to*. That is, whether the element exists before hand or not does not really matter.

---

If you also mean to update, then you need to consider also that option:

```
void f(map<string, Pair>& mymap, string c,int x, int y )
{
   auto res = mymap.insert( std::make_pair(c,Pair(x,y)) );
   if ( !res.second )
      res.first->second = Pair(x,y);
}
```

Basically the `insert` operation returns a pair of the iterator pointing at the key and a bool indicating if this `insert` created the object or if it was already there (in which case the value in the map is unmodified). By storing the result, we can test and if the `insert` did not create the value, we can update it through the returned iterator.

Comment: I think this won't update an element inside the map whereas his initial idea could do that (if Pair had a default constructor, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Calling `operator[]` on map will require your type to be default constructible. You can avoid that by using [map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) or [map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

Answer (score 2):

You will need a default contrructor:

```
Pair(): first () , second () {}
```

This is needed for the map's `operator[]`, which creates a default-constructed `mapped_type`
 when called with a non-existent key-

<strike>and a less-than operator that implements [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering):</strike>

```
struct Pair {
  // as before
  bool operator<(const Pair& rhs) const {
     / some code to implement less-than
  }
};
```

or you can pass a comparison functor or function implementinf strict weak ordering as a 
third template argument.

Comment: Sorry, I can not get why I need an ordering operator here?

Comment: @gartenzwerg You don't need it, my bad. You only need ordering if your type is a key of a map, or if you want to put it in an `std::set`

Answer (score 0):

The standard containers need a default constructor. They will use the `operator=` to set the correct value at some point after construction.

Comment: It needs one for `operator[]`, anyways. He can just use `insert` or even `emplace` in C++11.

Comment: @Xeo, I meant `operator=` of the type being contained, not the container itself.

Comment: They don't, really.. In this case — do not instantiate `operator[]` and you are good to go without a default constructor.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, that may be true for your implementation of `std::map` but I thought the standard required all contained types to be copyable? I can see that C++11 might relax that requirement for the initial insert but isn't it still true for subsequent operations?